# When would you have things like desu or masu twice or more in one sentence?

Tags: grammar

I was reading the sentence:

ホテルは高いから、友達のうちに泊まるつもりです,

and I thought, "Can't you also write the sentence as:"

ホテルは高いですから、友達のうちに泊まるつもりです.

But, then couldn't you also stick in だ after the 高い, (pretend 高い is not an I-adjective)

So I was just wondering, when would you use multiple です/ます、or when would you only use them one time? Could there be a time when you use both だ and です/ます?

ありがとうございます

Comment: on the side note, for the second sentence, ホテルは高いので、友達のうちに泊まるつもりですwould sound more natural.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use multiple です/ます when they can stand on their own as independent sentences. Like おいしいですから、たくさん食べました。When you seperate it, it can be " おいしいです。" and "たくさん食べました。"And normally the first sentence would be before ~が、~けど（S1+V1 but S1+S2)or ～から、～ので(Because S1+V1, S2+V2). For です then you can use as AですからB without "、".
And it's also grammarly correct if you remove  です before ~けど, ～から、～ので (for Ajective な you have to remove な + だ ) even if it was a formal sentence. For example: 健康は第一だから、納豆は人気です。But while we can have clause A in the plain form and clause B in the polite form, if you reverse it then the sentence (健康は第一ですから、納豆は人気だ) is grammarly wrong.
Also you can use twice when you quote a sentence, like: コウイチは 「納豆はおいしいです」 と言いました。